# Converting Unix time to DateTime 103

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a stored procedure that joins two tables of hotel booking data, however, the API that I pull my data from uses Unix time. I need to convert this to DateTime to match with my companies fields.

Currently, my conversion looks like this.

```
IIF([start] IS NOT NULL, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), [start], 103),'')  as 'ArrivalDate'
```

This just returns the value `1547310796` so no conversion has been done.

How do I convert the value to match 103 Date Time?

Comment: . . .  That is because your base value is not in desired format (i.e. `date`).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IIF` in the SQL standard). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, 1547310796 - DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')
```

The `DATEDIFF(second, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE())` part will give you how far *behind* you are from UTC time. You need to subtract that many seconds from the UTC timestamp to get the local time.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to come back to this and add another answer in that works if you just want the date and not time.

```
    SELECT cast(DATEADD(S,[start], '1970-01-01') as date) as 'ArrivalDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

works on Oracle/Sql

```
select TO_date ('19700101000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(<YOUR_COLUMN>+ decode (sessiontimezone, '+01:00', 3600, '+02:00', 7200, 0) , 'SECOND') as ArrivalDate
```

Comment: This is Oracle(?). The question is tagged "sql-server"

Comment: @HansKeﬆing no, not oracle.

Comment: "'to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name."